# Is there ANY context in which f(x,x) is noncommutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

Stupid question, but one occasionally reads such things as "the operation $\ast$ is noncommutative for all $x,y$ such that $x\neq y$" or "$x\ast y$  is commutative iff $x=y$". These statements bother me, because they imply that there is some operation $\cdot$ for which $x=y\not\implies x\cdot y=y\cdot x$ which in turn implies $x\cdot x\neq x\cdot x$.

Is this the result of poor writing, or is there some legitimate reason to call an operation between an element and itself "commutative".

Comment: The statements you give about non-commutativity fail if $y=x$

Comment: There are three options and we need to distinguish between them 1) They commute always; that's easy to express 2) they don't always commute or they sometimes don't commute.  That's easy to express 3) the third option is harder to express, they absolutely never commute.... except in the cases where they act on themselves, cause... you know if x=x you can't not switch them.. but that's the exception... all *real* cases they *don't* commute.  That third one requires some form af adress.

Comment: @fleablood: I have never encountered the third case arising "in nature" or seen any writing that needs to talk about operations that are "nowhere commutative". If the OP is reading material that needs to deal with that case, then he or she should definitely provide a reference, as the writing style used seems to be very poor from the OP's quotations.

Comment: @Rob Arthan that's why it *isn't* sloppy writing.  To describe a function that *never* (non-trivially) commutes we must [ne way or another that it *does* trivially commute.

Comment: I've never seen it either but clearly the OP has.  And in such a case we'd *have* to make an exception for the trivial case, wouldn't we.

Comment: See my answer for why it is sloppy writing, not because the logic behind the scenes is wrong, but because saying $1 * 2$ is or is not commutative is a category error: $1 * 2$ is a number not an operator. Also I am really intrigued to know if the OP is reading something that requires a concept of "nowhere commutative (except where necessary)".

Comment: This is sloppy language; instead of saying "$x \ast y$ is commutative" you should say "$x$ and $y$ commute."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't talking about when they do commute but when they don't.

There are three options.

1) For every $x\ne y $, $f (x,y)=f (y,x) $.  Thus we say $f$ always commute. (It's commutative)

2) For $x\ne y$ sometimes $f(x,y)\ne f (y,x) $.  Thus it's not always commutative. (It's not commutative.)

3) for $x\ne y $ we *always* have $f (x,y)\ne f (y,x) $.

We'd *like* to say of 3) that 3) is *never* commutative.

But we *can't* say that.  We can't say that because all functions have to commute when $x=y $.

So for 3) or only options are to state either it never commutes when $x\ne y $ or, equivalently, the *only* time $f $ commutes is if $x=y $.

> Is this the result of poor writing, or is there some legitimate reason to call an operation between an element and itself "commutative".

It's not poor writing.  Just the opposite. Proper writing *requires* that that case $x=y $ does commute.  Even if all others dont.

> or is there some legitimate reason to call an operation between an element and itself "commutative".

Well if $x=y $ then $f (x,y)=f (y,x) $.  That's a legitimate reason, isn't it.

Your seem to be saying it needn't be stated as it is always true.  Well, fair enough but the texts are stating we need to *always* make an exception because we are not allowed to say a function *never* commutes.  We must in those cases point out that $x=y $ is the only case the *do*.

Answer (score 4):

What you are reading looks to me like  sloppy writing. If $x = y$, then $x * y = y * x$ for any operator $*$ (for which $x *x$ is defined). An operator $*$ is commutative iff $x * y = y *x$ for all $x$ and $y$ (for which $x * y$ is defined). To prove this property, you only have to consider the case when $x \neq y$, but it is pointless and confusing to exclude this special case from the definition and it is wrong to say "$x * y$ is commutative": $x *y$ is a value in the algebraic structure and not an operator.

It does make sense to talk about commutativity on subsets of the domain of definition of an operator. E.g., you can say "multiplication is not commutative on the [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) $\Bbb{H}$, but is commutative on the complex numbers $\Bbb{C} \subseteq \Bbb{H}$". You can say "in the quaternions, commutativity of multiplications fails for the elements $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$". However, you don't say "$\mathbf{i}\mathbf{j}$ is non-commutative" or "$\mathbf{i}\mathbf{i}$ is commutative"($\mathbf{i}\mathbf{j}$ and $\mathbf{i}\mathbf{i}$" are not operations, but rather quaternions, namely $\mathbf{k}$ and $-1$).

Note: in the above, I am not attacking the usual abuse of notation whereby we write formulas with free variables and use them to denote functions (like "the function $f(x, y) = x + y + x*y$"). What you shouldn't do is talk about properties of the function in a context where you have constrained the free variables: to talk about properties (such as commutativity) of "the function $f(x, y)$ where $x = y$" is poor writing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the statement is simply saying "$x * y \ne y * x$ for all $x \ne y$."
Note that this is stronger than saying "there exists $x$ and $y$ such that $x * y \ne y * x$." You are correct that $x * x = x * x$ always, but this is not the point of the statement.